# Get index of dropdown/combobox by value (client side)?

Tags: javascript, html

I thought this would be simple, but is there a way to get the index of a value in a dropdown/combobox without looping through the items?

Comment: Is this an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/4405465) to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about select tag and you are trying to get the index of an option by it's value. If so, here is what you need to do:

```
// Get the select
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

// Get the option
var option = select.querySelector('option[value="myValue"]');

// Get the index of that option
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call( select.children, option );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.  You can do it natively with modern Javascript.

```
var myOption = document.querySelector('option[value="audi"]');
console.log(myOption.index); //returns index = 3
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/08qzLgbh/

Based on this HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> <!-- index 0 -->
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option> <!-- index 3 -->
</select>
```

Comment: Nice to see a version without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves jQuery and selectors, and is probably not all that efficient anyway, but it's probably what you want :

```
var o = $('option[value="something"]','#mycombo');
```

Simple enough (:

Comment: jQuery isn't necessary for this, nor is it tagged in the user's question.